# What materials can a palico steal?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I found a palico with Stealing as a forte, nd with the description that these palico can steal materials from monsters.

But I can't find any mention of what materials they can steal.

Can they steal whatever you can normally carve? Can they steal parts you can normally only get through breaking specific parts? Or can they only steal stuff you get from breaking a part if the part is broken at the time of the stealing? Or do they somehow conjure iron ore (or other gatherable stuff) from a monsters ears?

Comment: I don't have such a palico i can only talk from my experience in previuos games. If it is similar as previous iterations of the ability this means it can steal any of the carveable material, you get it as a reward in the end of the quest, but the chances ( in previous versions) where really low to steal anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anecdotally speaking, Stealing Palicos take their drops from the monster's body carve table. So, for example, if you're trying to get an item that's only available off the tail carve table, you won't be able to get it.

Comment: This has been my experience as well.

Comment: can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

The palicoes with a "steal" forte just steal anything over time. It happens kind of randomly, but I wouldn't expect anything more than one item off the carves. However, at one point, I got a Skymerald from one of my palicoes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Palicos can steal rares. Mine with a forte in stealing managed to steal a dissenter after I broke its face so it is possible.

Comment: What monster did it steal from?